# Entity Framework exception: Invalid object name 'Navigation'

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4, entity

I have an Entity Object called Navigation stored in a Database called Navigations. When I save the Entity calling

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

I get the error

> Invalid object name 'Navigation'.

I have removed the model and added it back in but with no change.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in a trigger that was referencing the table in a singular 'Navigation'.